# Dollar sign word file reading and assigning to a variable

Tags: linux, shell

This is my text file:

```
└─ $ ▶ cat myfile.txt
$FLD,abc
$FLD,xyz
$TRA,yyt
```

This is my environment variables:

```
└─ $ ▶ echo $FLD
/Users
└─ $ ▶ echo $TRA
/opt
```

What I want to do is getting the environment variable itself from file then change directory to that and execute the command in the 2nd column in the file.

```
└─ $ ▶ cat myscript.sh
IFS=","
while read f1 f2
do
target_folder=`echo $f1`
target_path=$f2
echo "It is going to be executed $target_path file in $target_folder folder"
cd $target_folder
done < myfile.txt
```

Because of dollar sign automatically escaped I could not change the folder and getting this error:

```
└─ $ ▶ sh myscript.sh
It is going to be executed abc file in $FLD folder
myscript.sh: line 7: cd: $FLD: No such file or directory
It is going to be executed xyz file in $FLD folder
myscript.sh: line 7: cd: $FLD: No such file or directory
It is going to be executed yyt file in $TRA folder
myscript.sh: line 7: cd: $TRA: No such file or directory
```

It is similar for this case:

```
└─ $ ▶ var1=$FLD
└─ $ ▶ var2=\$FLD
└─ $ ▶ cd $var1
└─ $ ▶ cd $var2
-bash: cd: $FLD: No such file or directory
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
IFS=","
while read f1 f2
do
    target_folder=$f1
    target_path=$f2
    eval "cd "$target_folder
done < myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

While using **`eval`** works in principle, its use **should generally be avoided for security reasons.**
For instance, your file's 1st column could conceivably contain arbitrary *commands*  that `eval` would then blindly execute.

From an error message in your question I infer that you're **using `bash`**, which allows use of extended regex matching with operator `=~` and indirect variable expansion to get a robust and safe solution:

```sh
while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2
do
  target_folder=$f1
  # Only try to expand the value if it starts with '$' and is followed by
  # a legal variable name, and nothing else.
  if [[ $target_folder =~ ^\$([_a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ ]]; then
    # Use variable indirection to get the variable's value.
    vname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    target_folder=${!vname}
  fi
  target_path=$f2
  echo "Executing file $target_path in folder $target_folder..."
  cd "$target_folder"
done < myfile.txt
```

- Note that Bash's [variable indirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection) still [allows injection of arbitrary commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41791071/45375), via array indices, hence the need to test the value of  `$target_folder` first.
- Also note the use of `IFS=','` directly before the `read` command, which scopes the change to that command without globally altering the value of `$IFS`.
- Also, `-r` is almost always the right option to use with `read`, so as to prevent unexpected interpretation of `\` chars. in the input.

---

A **POSIX-compliant solution** is also possible, but it requires the use of an external utility to test for a valid variable name, `sed` in this case:

```
while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2
do
  target_folder=$f1
  # Only try to expand the value if it is '$' followed by
  # a legal variable name, and nothing else.
  if [ -n "$(printf %s "$target_folder" | sed -n '/^\$[_a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/p')" ]; then
    # Given that we've ensured that $target_folder contains a valid variable reference,
    # we can now use `eval` safely.
    target_folder=$(eval "printf %s \"$target_folder\"")
  fi
  target_path=$f2
  echo "Executing file $target_path in folder $target_folder..."
  cd "$target_folder"
done < < myfile.txt
```

Note that even though `eval` is used (variable indirection is not part of the POSIX shell spec.), its use is safe in this case, because we've ensured that the string to be evaluated is nothing but a variable reference.